# PowerShell child script changes parent's environment

Tags: shell, powershell, environment

I have PS scripts that changes current working directory:

```
Set-Location (Join-Path (Split-Path -Parent (Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition)) -ChildPath src)
```

Unfortunately, it's affects parent process environment. So, when I am calling this script from terminal, the current directory is going to be changed after the script invocation. In Unix environment script can change only local current directory, as well as, environment variables for the script, not for the parent shell.

How it is possible to change this behavior?

Comment: One option would be to use Push-Location instead of Set-Location. Then just call Pop-Location at the end of the script.

Answer (score 1):

```
# Create a drive t: in the local scope whose root is c:\temp\backup
# drive t: disappears when the scope (function in this case) is exited
function test {
  New-PSDrive -name "t" -scope local -root c:\temp\backup -PSProvider filesystem; 
  ls t:
}
ls t: # fails unless t: already exists
test  # succeeds
ls t: # fails
```